# How do I append with a line break in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, append, vbulletin

I'm trying to put a line break before appending my variable so my output is cleaner.

This is what I have:

```
$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'] = fetch_template('drc_base').$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'];
```

which works like:

```
$foo = $bar.$foo;
```

or the non existing:

```
$foo =. $bar
```

So the template drc_base is some code, and begins/ends with a comment:

```
<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: drc_base -->


...CODE....


<!-- END TEMPLATE: drc_base -->
```

The way I have appended it, it adds that template to the beginning of the headinclude template, which is some meta tags pretty much.

When I view the source the output looks like this:

```
<!-- END TEMPLATE: drc_base --><meta http-equiv=.......
```

So for the sake of neat coding I want the output to be:

```
 <!-- END TEMPLATE: drc_base -->
 <meta http-equiv=
```

Is there anyway I can put a line break in this?  I have tried:

```
$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'] = fetch_template('drc_base')./n$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'];

$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'] = fetch_template('drc_base')./n.$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'];
```

and a few other variations with no luck =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a newline.

```
$x."\n".$y
```

That simple.

Comment: exactly what I was trying to do =) when of them "DOOOOHHH" moments lol, thanks! dang "s

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if works, but i think you're trying to concatenate, in the wrong way, and that's the correct way:

```
$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'] = fetch_template('drc_base')."\n\r".$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'];

$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'] = fetch_template('drc_base')."\r\n".$vbulletin->templatecache['headinclude'];
```

Comment: Also, i think the correct way is to append the new line at the end, but i'm never use the vbulletin, but at least, you learn the correct way to append string in php :)

Comment: whats the difference between using \n and \n\r ? using just the \n i achieved my goal, i was missing quotes -_- lol

Comment: \r means return carriage \n new line